# How to prove (p -> q) -> (~ p \/ q) in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove (p -> q) -> (~ p / q)  in Coq using the Axiom:

```
Axiom tautology : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~ P.
```

I am trying to convert ~ p / q into ~ p / p by applying p -> q. So do something like this:

```
Theorem Conversion: forall (p q: Prop),(p -> q) -> (~ p \/ q).
Proof.
  intros p q.
  intros p_implies_q.
  (do something here, change ~p\/q into ~p\/p)
  apply tautology...
```

But I don't know how can I do this. And if there is a better way to do this, please tell me. Thanks!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to use your `tautology` is with the tactic `destruct`. This allows you reduce to the cases where `p` is true and where `p` is not true.

```
Axiom tautology : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~ P.

Theorem Conversion: forall (p q: Prop),(p -> q) -> (~ p \/ q).
Proof.
  intros p q.
  intros p_implies_q.
  destruct (tautology p) as [p_true | p_not_true].
  - (* prove ~p \/ q using p *)
  - (* prove ~p \/ q using ~p *)
Qed.
```

Can you see how to prove `~p \/ q` in each of those cases?